# Error al inicializar firebase async/await

Tags: javascript, firebase, async-await

Estoy tratando de inicializar firebade mediante un json devuelto por `axios` para eso estoy implementado funciones asíncronas con `async/await`.

Este es mi código:

```
async function init() {
  try {
    var _app = await axios.post('/app');
    var config = _app.data;
    if (!firebase.apps.length) {
      firebase.initializeApp(config);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    Sentry.captureException(e);
  }
  return {
    storage: function() {
      return firebase.storage();
    },
    database: function() {
      return firebase.firestore();
    }
  };
}
var app = init();
export default app;
```

Pero me surgen estos errores al momento de ejecutar el codigo

> app.storage() is not a function
>
> app.database() is not a function

Cabe recalcar que es un módulo que estoy exportando con webpack para un entorno web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una función async siempre devuelve una promesa.

```js
async function init() {
  return {
    saludar: function() {}
  };
}
var app = init();
console.log({
  'Es promesa?': app instanceof Promise,
  'De qué tipo es app.saludar?': typeof app.saludar
});
```

Y esa promesa no tiene las propiedades del objeto con que se resolverá. Para acceder a éste debes manejar la resolución en el componente que usará firebase invocándola con `await`

```
let firebaseAdmin=await firebaseFactory;
```

o con

```
Promise.resolve(firebaseFactory).then(firebaseAdmin=>{...})
```

Por ejemplo:

import app from './firebase_factory.js';

```
class Componente {

   constructor() {
      this.firebaseFactory = app;
   }
   async storeImage(name, image) {
      let firebaseAdmin = await this.firebaseFactory,
      uploadRef = firebaseAdmin.storage().ref().child(name),
      return uploadRef.put(image) <--- esto no me acuerdo si retorna una promesa
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba de la siguiente forma, puede que solucione tu problema:

```js
export default async function init() {
    try {
      var _app = await axios.post('/app');
      var config = _app.data;
      if (!firebase.apps.length) {
        firebase.initializeApp(config);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      Sentry.captureException(e);
    }
    return {
      storage: function() {
        return firebase.storage();
       },
      database: function() {
        return firebase.firestore();
      }
    };
}
```

En el archivo donde se quisiera ejecutar, simplemente se importaría de la siguiente manera:

```js
import app from '../../ruta-archivo'; // Opción 1
const app = require('/../../ruta-archivo'); // Opción 2

app.init() // para ejecutar la función
```

Comment: De echo ya lo había intentado de esa forma, incluso termine creando un clase en javascript para eso, pero me sigue dando el mismo error o me dice que tengo que inicializar firebase con `app.initializeApp`